# shared L2 in multicore: regarding miss per kilo instruction (MPKI) counting

Tags: cpu, multi-core, cpu-cache

I am using multicore simulator marss http://marss86.org. I am using 4-core simulation, with shared L2 cache. Each core is run for say, 100M instructions. Since different cores progress at different rates, I collect stats only for 100M instruction of each core. The overall simulation runs till the last-to-finish core has done 100M instructions.

I wanted to calculate MPKI (miss-per-Kilo-instruction) for L2. I was not clear, whether MPKI should be

```
Sum_Of_L2_Miss_Of_All_Cores/ 400M
```

or

```
Sum_Of_L2_Miss_Of_All_Cores/ 100M
```

or something else. Can you clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MPKI is

> Sum_Of_L2_Miss_Of_All_Cores/ 400K

(note the K--its MP*K*I not misses per instruction) since 400M instructions were executed.  It might help to imagine the workload being run on one core with very fine-grained context switching with no OS overhead and with per thread miss counts maintained.